# cordova-plugin-background-mode Is not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm starting at **cordova** and I'm trying to make a simple application that runs in the background.

I'm using this package: [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/lkonzen-garupa/cordova-plugin-background-mode)

In this simulation, I run the command `cordova run android`, when it opens in the emulator and I close it to see if the beep will run with the app closed.

The strange thing is that the beep is not playing in the background.

What am I doing wrong?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            navigator.notification.beep(5);
        }, 7000);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have also the same problem. Mobile programming is so frustrating!

Comment: Have you got solution? I am also stucked in it.

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama Hello, I did not continue the project, but soon I will need this resource.

Comment: @Tiago I didn't got the solution so you can use the event listeners. I can show you the example if you are not familiar with it. In my case I have to play audio in background so I used ionic native media plugin instead of ionic native audio plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For running a function when application is minimized, permission for running service in foreground is required.

Android target 9 (API Level 28) or higher using foreground services requires permission for FOREGROUND_SERVICE.

In your configuration file add the following permission request: *<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/ >*